# Redirecting ServerAlias root to some sub-directory with Apache

Tags: virtualhost, redirect, apache-2.4

I have the following **Apache** *VirtualHost* configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 192.0.2.1:80 [2001:DB8:4007:80d::200e]:80>
    ServerName app.example.com
    ServerAlias foo.example.com
    ServerAlias bar.example.com
    ... other server aliases ...
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd like to (temporary) redirect `http://foo.example.com/` to `http://foo.example.com/path/foo/resource`, and more generically:

`http://${sub}.example.com/` > `http://${sub}.example.com/path/${sub}/resource`

What's the best way to do it? *If it's not possible generically,* I do not mind having to write a rule for each ServerAlias.